# Netbeans 8. Mark lines to go to them quickly

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm looking for a way to mark lines in Netbeans 8.2 to be able to switch between them with a shortcut. For those who know Notepad++, you can mark lines by clicking next to the line number and switch between them just pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>. That's what I want.

If Netbeans doesn't have this useful shortcut, is there any plugin which make this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Netbeans has bookmarks feature. You can right-click on the left toolbar of required file, choose `Bookmarks -> Toggle Bookmark` (or press `Ctrl+Shift+M`) or press `Toggle Bookmark` button in the file top toolbar. Then you can navigate through bookmarks using the same popup (`Bookmarks -> Next Bookmark`, `Bookmarks -> Previous Bookmark`) or down/up buttons in the file top toolbar. But also you can use `Ctrl+Shift+Period` and `Ctrl+Shift+Comma` to navigate between bookmarks (you can change these shortcuts in the `Tools -> Options -> Keymap` popup).

Comment: Wow. Awesome feature! Even better than I expected. You saved me a lot of time, thank you so much!